# Improve RegEx to Highlight Text on page using given search terms

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js

I have some working code here that highlights exact matches of a given search term.

```
highlight: function(html, search) {
        $.each(search.split(' '), function(idx, word) {
            if (word != '') {
                html = html.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), '<mark>' + word + '</mark>')
            }
        });
        return html;
}
```

I'd like to highlight "less than exact matches" as well.

**For example:**  "9375551234" should highlight "(937) 555-1234"
         **or:**  "oneil" should highlight "O'neil"

**Notice:** I am replacing the match with 'word' rather than the matched content.  The solution should place '' around the original content.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Searching for "fuzzy regex javascript" throws up lots of useful results. You can also give this [gist](https://gist.github.com/samknight/8863745) a shot

Answer (score 1):

You can modify you search word to accept any special character after or before it

```
word = "9375551234"
regex_word = ""
for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
 regex_word += '[^\\w]*' + word[i];
};

"(937) 555-1234".replace(new RegExp(regex_word, 'gi'), 's'); // 's'
```

and for this one:

```
word = "oneil"
regex_word = ""
for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  regex_word += '[^\\w]*' + word[i];
};
new RegExp(regex_word, 'gi')
s = "O'ne-il".replace(new RegExp(regex_word, 'gi'), 's'); // 's'
```

so for you will be

```
highlight: function(html, search) {
    $.each(search.split(' '), function(idx, word) {
        if (word != '') {
          regex_word = ""
          for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
             regex_word += '[^\\w]*' + word[i];
          };

            html = html.replace(new RegExp(regex_word, 'gi'), '<mark>' + word + '</mark>')
        }
    });
    return html;
}
```